# Possible to access a dictionary in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to think of ways to import random words into an app that I'm working on and I was thinking that the iPhone has an auto correct library for certain words, so my question is this:

Does the iPhone have dictionary that developers can pull from? And if so, how might one do this? And if not, does anyone have any ideas how I might do that, without entering them all in on my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple announced that access to a system wide dictionary will be available in [iOS5](http://www.tipb.com/2011/06/06/apple-announces-ios-5-1500-api-developers-200-features-users/). However, If you need to discuss it further, you will probably want to post a question in the developer forums since the details of the API are probably still covered under NDA.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such dictionary API from which you may use for your mentioned purpose.

Comment: but I'm not so much interested in a dictionary as I am interested in a word data bank.